# error: duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed in visualizing index of PCA with FAMD

Tags: r

I have a dataset named df with 22 variables and 10000 rows. I am trying to reduce the dimensions of my data using PCA. After removing the target variable, the dataset has 21 variables and 10000 rows. Since my data has both categorical and numerical variables, I am using FAMD technique. I can visualize graph of variables but I cannot visualize the factor maps for the individuals. The following works well for me:

```
library(factoextra)

explan_df <- df[,!(names(df) %in% classCol)]
df_famd <- FAMD(explan_df, graph=TRUE)

fviz_famd_var(df_famd,col.var = "cos2")
```

[image: the first rows eight rows of df_famd$var$cos2 looks like this. It is a matrix with 21 rows (variables) and 5 columns (PCs)]

But when I run the code below, I get the error :

> Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) :    duplicate 'row.names'
> are not allowed In addition: Warning message: non-unique values when
> setting 'row.names': ‘0’, ‘1’

```
fviz_famd_ind(df_famd,col.ind = "cos2")
```

[image: The first eight rows of df_famd$ind$cos2 looks like this. It is a matirx of 10000 rows (data) and 5 columns (PCs)]

the class for both ind and var are as following:

"matrix" "array"

I want to visualize the data in 2D graph using FAMD. How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these:

```
rownames(explan_df)<-NULL
#or
rownames(explan_df) = make.names(rownames(explan_df), unique=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both, but it keeps giving the same error. I am not sure why var column does not have the same problem. They are both done on the same dataset

Comment: Could you please provide a minimum sample of your data and also your code for importing data that throws the same error? So that it would be easily understandable and find the issue faster.

Comment: Also `str(explan_df)` and `length(duplicated(rownames(explan_df))==TRUE)` would be great to provide.